# Wildcard-like syntax in an eloquent Where clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is a where clause I have:

```
->where( 'post_type', '=', 'blog' )
```

Is there any way to replace 'blog' by a wildcard, so it will match any 'post_type' ?

Full query:

```
$db = ( new DbSql() )->db()->getConnection();
$postsCount = $db->table( 'posts' )
                          ->where( 'status', '=', 'published' )
                          ->where( 'post_type', '=', 'blog' )
                          ->where( 'alerts', '<', Settings::CONTENT_ALERT_NUMBER_ALLOWANCE )
                         ->count() ?? null;
```

Comment: Just remove the statement

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [`like`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses):

```
->where('post_type', 'like', '%'.$string.'%')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$query->where($field, 'like', $input . '%');
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are storing **blog** in any variable, say `$blog`.

```
if($blog) {
    $query->where('post_type', '=', $blog);
}
```

If blog is empty, do not add the where condition.

**Edit :**

I assume you are using Laravel query builder.

```
$postsQuery = $db->table( 'posts' )
                          ->where( 'status', '=', 'published' );
if($blog){
    $postQuery->where( 'post_type', '=', $blog );
}
$postCount = $postQuery->where( 'alerts', '<', Settings::CONTENT_ALERT_NUMBER_ALLOWANCE )
                         ->count() ?? null;
```

Comment: how do you insert this into an eloquent statement ? Please show a full query with this.

Comment: Please add your query.

Comment: added on original post.

Comment: What is `$db` in this? Are you using `DB` facade?

Comment: Added. I use eloquent outside laravel. So it basically returns a capsule instance.