# Wildcard-like syntax in an eloquent Where clause to search between two strings

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I saw the answer provided in this question [Wildcard-like syntax in an eloquent Where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492310/wildcard-like-syntax-in-an-eloquent-where-clause/69895200#69895200) now I want to know if is there a way to search between two strings?.

basicasicaly in my code I want to show requests that have a status of new or scheduled.

```
$requests = DB::table('requests')
        ->select('requestDate','requestTime','status','requestID')
        ->where('requestorID', '=',$userID)
        ->where('status', 'LIKE','%New%')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I suggest at least browsing the docs when you're stuck - they really are pretty clear and answer most simple questions like this.  AFAICT one solution for what you're after is a `where()` (for `requestorID`) combined with a `where()` and an `orWhere()` (for `status`). [The docs describe exactly what you need](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) ,The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

```
$requests = DB::table('requests')
        ->select('requestDate','requestTime','status','requestID')
        ->where('requestorID', '=',$userID)
        ->whereIn('status', ['new','scheduled'])
        ->get();
```

Comment: The reason I did not suggest whereIn, is because LIKE was used in the question. If the value is exactly 'new' or 'scheduled' , this is the best solution.

Comment: @GertB., what if i had a state called almostNew, this is why is used whereIn

Comment: Well indeed, With the Like in the question i was confused, thats why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
->where('status', 'new')
->orWhere('status', 'scheduled')
```

Comment: in that case the where requestorID will not work when status is 'scheduled'

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a where with an orWhere:

```
$requests = DB::table('requests')
        ->select('requestDate','requestTime','status','requestID')
        ->where('requestorID', '=',$userID)
        ->where(function($q) {
          $q->where('status', 'LIKE','%New%');
          $q->orWhere('status', 'LIKE','%Scheduled%');
       
        })->get();
```